# Symfony 4 - PHP convert multidimensional array to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, symfony

Hello I've this array in Symfony on my controller:

```
    $array = [
        "label" => [
            "january",
            "february"
        ],
        "data" => [
            0,
            1
        ]
    ];

I wish I could convert it for use in Javascript.
```

The goal is that I can get in JS:

["january", "february"]
and
[0,1]

to use them as array variables

I tried `json_encode($array)`, it works but I can't access to my array using `{{array["label"}}` in Twig in the Javascript block

Can someone help me please ?

EDIT : Okay guys, it works now, I did this :

**Controller :**

```
    return $this->render('products/index.html.twig', [
        "report" => json_encode($report),
    ]);
```

**index.html.twig (javascript bloc)**

```
const data = {{report | raw}};
```

Thanks all !

Comment: Please, add to your question the part of your controller that return the response and your twig, where you try to read your data.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to call JSON.parse since the output of json_decode is a javascript literal. Just assign it to a variable.

```
var yourArray = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
```

You can access property like this

```
alert(yourArray[0].Key);
```

Comment: No it doesn't work, I've this error : ```Impossible to access a key ("0") on a string variable ("{"label":["January","February"],"data":["0","1"]}").
```

Comment: Try like this `yourArray[0][1]` or Try like this `alert(yourArray[0].1);` See here how to access data in array https://jsfiddle.net/9f5zn2s6/

Answer (score 0):

What you get is a Json string, not an object, you first have to parse it in Javascript.

```
const data=JSON.parse(array);
```

Comment: Incorrect, if this was being pulled into a JS string then yeah that would be the case, but since we are using PHP we can literally just assign the json_encode result by echoing it into the script like: `let arr = <?=json_encode($array); ?>;`

Comment: No it doesn't work, I've this error in the console :``` Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&' ```

Comment: @JoshWood he's in his twig view, not in a simple HTML/PHP model. What you're suggesting isn't going to works

Comment: @Preciel My apologies then

Answer (score 0):

You can try use:

PHP:

```php
$array = [
    "label" => [
        "january",
        "february"
    ],
    "data" => [
        0,
        1
    ]
];
$response = new Response(json_encode($array));
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return $response;
```

JavaScript:

```js
var data = JSON.parse(response);
console.log(data.label)
```

Hope help you.

Comment: Argh, no it doesn't work. I'm using Symfony, so I've to access my variable using ```var data = JSON.parse({{response}})```

But it doesn't work

Comment: @eronn could you please provide here dd(data)?